# Loading Iframe Facebook (Load denied by X-Frame-Options)

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

My team is in charge of some difficulties with an app on Facebook. We believe this occurred some error in loading the iframe. We discovered this error through Firebug:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=140656472747871&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fnuvemapps.com.br%2Fci%2Fncupons%2Fhome%2F%3Ffb_source%3Dsearch%26ref%3Dts%26fref%3Dts&state=32e667a3645c047d751d20811d49ef6b&req_perms=email%2C+publish_steram%2C+manage_pages does not permit framing.

This happens mainly with people who have not allowed the app, so we do not know specifically where this problem is starting. We still have three possible causes left:

- Server Configuration
- Problem with our coding
- Or in our setup facebook app dev

Can anyone help in identifying this error?

Here is the link to the app:
https://apps.facebook.com/cupomigo

Comment: Isn't this a security thing? If you could load facebook login into an iframe then you could do click jacking.

Comment: If you're in control of the server this is running on, check what security middleware you might be using. For example, I'm running a node server and I had to disable xssFilter middleware and frameguard middleware. Now this error is gone.

Answer (score 22):

I used `target="_top"` for the link, and it is now working perfectly.

Comment: In Page Tab App case, it won't work, as it will navigate away from Page Tab

Comment: If you're inside of a Canvas based app, this will also break out of the iFrame and take the user to the self-hosted application. Not desirable.

Comment: where did I use target="_top" ??

Comment: They're trying to login from within an iframe. They have an anchor tag <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=....etc" target="_top">LOGIN TO FACEBOOK</a>. This will go to the iframes parent window (and its parent window if there is on, etc) and take the whole window to that url. If you are trying to use an iframe for logging your main window into facebook this won't help.

Comment: Thank you @Altaf, that helped :)

Comment: really you saved me!

Answer (score 3):

Use this line given below instead of header() function.

```
echo "<script>window.top.location = 'https://apps.facebook.com/yourappnamespace/';</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=""
```

Before your link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href="https://yourlink.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same error, but for the comment plugin, I don't know if it helps but I solved it by inserting the moderation or administration meta-tag

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="&#123;YOUR_APP_ID&#125;" />
```

Anyway, if the user is not logged into Facebook you will still have the same problem.
I hope I have been helpful, good work.