# Facebook PHP SDK and Tab Pages - login and signed_request

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I'm making a Facebook app to be used in tab page, the point of the app is people to upload picture and share it so that other can see and vote for it. So i know i must use `app_data` to redirect user to the specific picture but i cant handle it. I was trying with `$facebook->getSigned_request`, `$_REQUEST` but none of them returned the app_data value. Also im using PHP SDK example file for login but when i try it from the tab page nothing happende. Can you tell me how to login from the tab page and receive the `app_data` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, from the beginning. First of all, when user gets to your page, you have to check whether or not that user has given your app permissions.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_SECRET
));

if($facebook->getUser()) {
    //Here will be code to get app_data
} else {
    $params = array(); //Here you will enter key=>value pairs of permissions you need
    echo '<script>top.location.href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl($params) . '"</script>';
    //Code above redirects user to page that will ask for permissions for your app.
}
```

Code above will user login and permissions. Now in order to get app_data you will have to do this:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest(); //getting signed_request
$app_data = $signed_request['app_data']; // getting app_data
```

Now, in order to get app_data you need to make sure that you pass it to your tab in URL (GET). like so

```
PATH_TO_YOUR_FB_PAGE/?app_data=SOME_VALUE
```

or if your page ends with `?sk=app_PAGE_ID`, just add `&app_data=SOME_VALUE`

Comment: @c0nfus3d1 glad it helped :) Do note, the answer is 1 year old, and some things might have changed. Use with caution.

Comment: your explanation was spot on though for what I was looking for! not sure why it didn't work for @Georgi

Comment: @Darvex the ```getLoginUrl``` method generates a link to login using OAuth? I have tried that but the page doesn't load in the fb tab. In the console I see a message: ```Refused to display```.

Comment: @JCarlos this answer is over 2 years old, some things might've changed. But you could look up the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915152/loading-iframe-facebook-load-denied-by-x-frame-options maybe it has something to do with the error you're seeing