# Facebook 'like button' return X-Frame-Options Deny

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

I'm trying to put a facebook 'like button' on each post of a blog. The code was pasted correctly, but i'm getting this error:

`Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/undefined/plugins/like.php?action=recommend&app_id…%2F&layout=button_count&locale=pt_BR&sdk=joey&share=false&show_faces=false' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.`

There is a 'undefined' after facebook.com/, and i don't know why.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Which version of the Javascript SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using the code offered by the page when i click in 'Get Code'. I think it is 2.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading Iframe Facebook (Load denied by X-Frame-Options)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915152/loading-iframe-facebook-load-denied-by-x-frame-options)

Comment: Not a duplicate - this is a separate issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is unfortunately a bug in how the JS SDK does implicit initialization (the init params in the url), so you're doing everything correct.

A fix is being prepared, but for now, you can use `/en_US/all.js` instead of `/en_US/sdk.js`.

Comment: Same issue here since a few days.... Tried to use all.js instead of sdk.js but no luck...

Comment: Latest occurrence of the issue: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/854001531875629/ as of 08 July 2021. So they break it periodically :-(

Comment: did't work for my error "Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'."

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but a new problem - see also the new comment from @gkpo

Sorry, I can't comment (low reputation) but I tried several things to resolve the Facebook 'Like Plugin' issue.

The Facebook like.php returns a DENY for X-Frame-Options.

So I tried to renew the script [Facebook plugin like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/). **-> Does not work.**

I tried setting up X-frame options for my page (allow Facebook). **-> Does not work.**

Then I tried to link my page with [Facebook business manager](https://business.facebook.com/) (there is an option to link pages with verification).
I thought this is the solution because the like button was back, but the secret was my Facebook login.

**The plugin does not return DENY if you are logged into Facebook.**

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of the server this is running on, check what security middleware you might be using. For example, I'm running a node server and I had to disable xssFilter middleware and frameguard middleware and now it runs.