# facebook login button not working on ios (phonegap)

Tags: cordova

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? In chrome, i got error in console

```
Refused to display 'https://mobile.facebook.com/v2.7/dialog/oauth?...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

my facebook button is not working.

This my javascript

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {

    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'myappid',
            cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                            // the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.7' // use graph api version 2.5
        });
    };

    function fb_login(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("loggedin", 1);
                window.location.assign("3.html");
             });
            } else {
             alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});

    }

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

and this my html

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<button onclick="fb_login();">Facebook</button>
```

please help(sorry for my english)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook 'like button' return X-Frame-Options Deny](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417208/facebook-like-button-return-x-frame-options-deny)