# Embed YouTube video - Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: html, django, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to feed my Django page with some resource I am getting from somewhere else.

Inside the feed, I have YouTube videos with URL like: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6XUVjK9W4o`

Once I added this into my page, the video does not show up, saying:

> Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6XUVjK9W4o' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Then I said, well, what if I change `watch` to `embed`. Then YouTube player shows up, but no video, saying:

[image: Enter code here]

How can I get this to work?

I am showing it in HTML like this:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
    src="{{vid.yt_url}}">
</iframe>
```

I googled almost for an hour, but no sign of success. I tried to append `&output=embed` - nada...

Comment: Here is how Youtube video API works: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Answer (score 603, accepted):

You must ensure the URL contains **embed** rather **watch** as the `/embed` endpoint allows outside requests, whereas the `/watch` endpoint does not.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A6XUVjK9W4o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: For anyone that is wondering, the reason this works is because the /embed endpoint allows outside requests, whereas the /watch endpoint does not.

Comment: Should really add a WHY in the answer instead of just the piece of code...

Comment: @NyiMaLayWinLaeAye But what if my video src is dynamic? I am stuck to this point

Comment: I tried using the "youtu.be" link that I copied from the address bar of the video I wanted to embed -- yes, I changed watch to embed -- but it didn't like that.  I changed to youtube.com + the path and it worked.

Answer (score 94):

The YouTube URL in `src` must have and use the `embed` endpoint instead of `watch`, so for instance let’s say you want to embed this YouTube video: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6N9782MzFQ` (browser's URL).

You should use the `embed` endpoint, so the URL now should be something like `https://www.youtube.com/embed/P6N9782MzFQ`. Use this value as the URL in the `src` attribute inside the iframe tag in your HTML code, for example:

`<iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/P6N9782MzFQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ng-show="showvideo"></iframe>`

So just replace `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` with `https://www.youtube.com/embed/` and of course check for your video's ID. In this sample, my video ID is `P6N9782MzFQ`.

Comment: Just replace "watch?v=" with "embed/"

Answer (score 28):

You only need to copy <iframe> from the YouTube Embed section (click on SHARE below the video and then EMBED and copy the entire iframe).

Comment: This solution was much more clear

Comment: Thanks. A simple answer is a better answer

Answer (score 5):

If embed no longer works for you, try with `/v` instead:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/A6XUVjK9W4o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with the embed, I also had to install the Google Cast extension in my browser.

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4u856utdR94" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```