# YouTube and FancyBox Video Functionality

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, fancybox-2

I am trying to embed a YouTube video in the actual page, and then have another video in a lightbox using the FancyBox plugin. When I do this, I get:

Refused to display 'YouTube video URL' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I would like the video on the page to autoplay, and the video in the lightbox to play when it is clicked and pause the video embedded on the page. Any help is appreciated in solving this, I haven't worked much with YouTube API or FancyBox.

**EDIT:**

I was able to embed two videos, one on the page and one in a lightbox with the help of this: 
[embed youtube video - Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661182/embed-youtube-video-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-opti)

In case, anyone needs this question answered in the future. Changing a URL from watch to embed allows for this.

Anyone able to help on the play/stop functionality using FancyBox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to embed two videos, one on the page and one in a lightbox with the help of this: embed youtube video - Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

In case, anyone needs this question answered in the future. Changing a URL from watch to embed allows for this.