# Django: How to embed a video in <iframe> using the URL sourced from the database in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a Django app that displays a list of videos (ListView). On clicking each item in the ListView, I get directed to DetailView where that specific video is displayed. I am trying to accomplish this by:
[image]

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
    {% block content %}
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
        <div class="post-entry">
        <div class="card" style="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <!-- sourcing the URL directly -->
            <iframe 
                width="560" 
                height="315" 
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T9ikpoF2GH0" 
                title="YouTube video player" 
                frameborder="0" 
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
                allowfullscreen>
            </iframe></br>
            <!-- sourcing URL from django model -->
            <iframe 
                width="560" 
                height="315" 
                src="{{object.URL}}"
                title="YouTube video player" 
                frameborder="0" 
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
                allowfullscreen>
            </iframe></br>
            <!-- info from model -->
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Video </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Audio </a>
            <div class="">
                <h5 class="card-title text-left"> Title: {{object.title}}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-text  text-left ">Guest: {{object.guest_firstName}} {{object.guest_lastName}}</h6>
                <h6 class="card-text  text-left ">Host: {{object.host_firstName}} {{object.host_lastName}}</h6>
                <h6 class="card-text  text-left ">Description: {{object.description}} </h6>
                <h6 class="card-text  text-left ">Topics: {{object.topics}} </h6>
                <h6 class="card-text  text-left ">Date Published: {{object.date_published}} </h6>
                <h6 class="card-text  text-left "> URL: {{object.URL}} </h6>
            </div>
            </br>
        </div>
        </div>


    {% endblock content %}
```

I can see that the URL as a text is modeled properly.

[image]

This is how it's supposed to look. The image below shows the embedded video by hard passing the URL in the . But I want to pass the URL dynamically to the `src="<URL sourced to database>"` from the database.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please paste all relevant code of template instead of posting images?

Comment: I updated the codes from the template for your reference.

Comment: Does the video successfully saved in media files?, can you please also share settings.py for media files , relevant models and views?

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure the URL contains **embed** rather **watch** as the `/embed` endpoint allows outside requests, whereas the `/watch` endpoint does not.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A6XUVjK9W4o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You're tying doing this instead:

```
<iframe src="https://youtu.be/T9ikpoF2GHO" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25661346/1242842

Comment: I have `/embed` in the video URL

Comment: @SL4566 can you share the generated HTML via https://dpaste.org/?

Comment: @SL4566 I just looked at the your code and you're trying to embed `https://youtu.be/T9ikpoF2GHO` which won't work.

Comment: I do not know why the video does not work anymore. Here's another embedded code. I could not still figure it out.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3XOKpLgSJtI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: @SL4566 works if you add the protocol `https://` or `http://` depending whether your environment is https or http.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience and I solved it by adding video id after embed. In your case it should be as

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YourVideoId" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```