# Facebook comments disabled on all pages of website due to "X-frame-options" set to "deny"

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, x-frame-options

I use Facebook comments on every page on my website, using their [Comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/).

Recently, I noticed that the comments on every web page have stopped showing up, giving the following error in the console:

```
 Refused to display [url] in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Full error:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/feedback.php?app_id&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D44%23cb%3Df2f5722dfd41%26domain%3Dtheinternet.io%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftheinternet.io%252Ffb2882a8d21d58%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=1904&height=100&href=https%3A%2F%2Ftheinternet.io%2Ftest-page.html&locale=en_US&numposts=5&sdk=joey&version=v3.3&width=550' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Further, when I put in any url from my website into the [Comments Plugin Code Generator from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/), an example of the comments box won't even show.

I've tried setting links to target="_top", as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555592/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-deny-facebook), but that did not change anything.

If you want to recreate the problem, [here is a test page](https://theinternet.io/test-page.html).

Comment: When I visit the link in the log, facebook says: Warning: This Message Contains Blocked Content
Your message couldn't be sent because it includes content that other people on Facebook have reported as abusive.

Comment: Thank you, after checking the Sharing Debugger, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, it states that my website doesn't meet the Community Standards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), it turns out my website is blocked for not meeting the Community Standards, receiving this error: "We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know."