# Facebook passport authentication: "Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'."

Tags: facebook, heroku, express, passport.js

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=XXXXX&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.2%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252FX%252Fauth%252Ffacebook%252Fcallback%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%XXXX%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=http%3A%2F%2FXXXX%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

I'm adding Facebook authentication to my Express app, and I'm getting this error only when I upload and try it on Heroku (I don't receive this error on localhost).
Here's my server code:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
 clientID: 'x',
 clientSecret: 'x',
 callbackURL: 'http://x/auth/facebook/callback'
 },
 function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  (DB query)        
 }
));

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
                                      failureRedirect: '/auth/facebook' }));
```

Then I'm just doing a simple link to log in:

```
<a href="/auth/facebook/">
    <img src="facebooklogin.png" alt="Log in with Facebook">
</a>
```

I've tried to find a solution from other people's questions but to no avail, I'm just using the Passport's Facebook strategy in the same way as the example on their site. And again, I it works fine if I change the site URL from developers.facebook.com to localhost and try to log in that way, and after I've allowed it on an account I can log in with that account when it's on Heroku as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've discovered that this is only a problem with my domain. I have this domain forwarding to x.herokuapp.com with domain masking on goDaddy. So when I go to x.herokuapp.com and try to log in, it works fine.

Comment: try to add `target="_top"` as seen in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915152/loading-iframe-facebook-load-denied-by-x-frame-options

Answer (score 0):

try changing your callback url on the facebook app at the developer page when you upload the app to heroku, to the fully qualified URL e.g "example.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook/callback"

Comment: Assuming you mean the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" field, that didn't work for me. I couldn't find any other callback fields.

Comment: also domain masking hides the url so facebook cant actually verify your URL. what is the url of the hosted app and what is in the facebook callback field

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add `target="_top"`?
I did this and it fixed my issue.

as seen in:

> [Loading Iframe Facebook (Load denied by X-Frame-Options)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915152/loading-iframe-facebook-load-denied-by-x-frame-options)