# Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. (Plugin Facebook-comments Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments, x-frame-options

i'm adding facebook comments plugin from this web [plugin comment facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments?locale=id_ID) , but i get error Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny' . I've tried various ways but the result is zonk, please help me..  I'm using laravel 8
i tried using this method [target="_top"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915152/loading-iframe-facebook-load-denied-by-x-frame-options) but can't, i also tried this but its not working

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
  {
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN', false);
    return $response;

  }
```

Comment: Are you using apache ?

Comment: from what I see this plugin is a front-end only plugin (so PHP or Laravel should not apply). Can you share the exact steps you took to embed it?

Comment: @KenLee yes i use apache

Comment: @apokryfos i copied and pasted the code snippet from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments?locale=id_ID to my blade, when i clear cache it works perfectly, but when i login facebook then i get this error

Comment: @KenLee I've looked for the x-frame-options setting in httpd.conf but couldn't find it

Comment: Of course you won't find it on your end - and your attempt to _set_ it, is also pointless. This is a response header sent _by_ the site that was attempted to display inside the iframe - so that's Facebook, not you.

Comment: @CBroe then what should i do? I'm really dizzy with this

Comment: I am currently getting the same result, so it might be that Facebook broke something once again. I'd recommend keeping an eye on their bug tracker / status report page.